# On the installation of mpi.h for C in Ubuntu

Tags: c, mpi

I would like to start with MPI/C and I want to compile/execute the standard program mpi_hello.
I succeeded regarding mpicc but I got an error message when I compile the file.
Here is the program:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])

{

int mynode, totalnodes;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);

  printf( "\nHello world from process %d of %d\n", mynode, totalnodes );
  if(totalnodes==1) printf("You have just one processor!\n");
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

I got the following:

```
turb@turb-LIFEBOOK-AH531:~/Desktop/Prog$ mpicc mpi_hello.c
turb@turb-LIFEBOOK-AH531:~/Desktop/Prog$ cc -O3 mpi_hello.c
mpi_hello.c:6:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mpi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!
a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MPI you are nor allowed to use cc -O3 name.c to compile your program. The correct command for compilation is: mpicc -O3 name.c. The command mpicc name.c has nothing to do here. 
Here is what you get for just one proc:

```
turb@turb-LIFEBOOK-AH531:~/Desktop/Prog$ mpicc -O3 mpi_hello.c
turb@turb-LIFEBOOK-AH531:~/Desktop/Prog$ ./a.out

Hello world from process 0 of 1
You have just one processor!
```

You may also use for more than one processor (e.g. 2) mpirun -np 2 ./a.out as mentioned above. I hope this could help a bit!

Comment: mpicc is just a wrapper around your C compiler. It is not required to compile an MPI program. You can usually see what mpicc actually calls if you run `mpicc -show`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

```
module add gcc mpich2
mpicc mpi_hello.c
```

?

Edit:  Oh wow, I completely misread your post.  You successfully compiled it by the looks of it with 
    mpicc hello_world.c

Now you should be able to execute a.out with

```
mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
```

where 2 = the number of processors.
Using your code and a fresh install:

```
beaty@korriban:~$ mpicc test.c
beaty@korriban:~$ mpirun ./a.out

Hello world from process 0 of 1
You have just one processor!

beaty@korriban:~$ mpirun -np 2 ./a.out

Hello world from process 0 of 2

Hello world from process 1 of 2
```

Comment: Ah.  I suppose that is specific to my university cluster.

You installed on ubuntu via:
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc
?

Comment: Thank you wbt11a for your answer. Yes! It works well. However, module add gcc mpich2 is always ignored. I get: module: command not found. Furthermore, we don't compile the file. Actually, I have a more complicated program and I have to compile it. Using cc -O3 gives a fatal error: mpi.h not such a file of directory! How strange!!

Comment: Don't worry about the module add commands.  That was my mistake.
Are you able to run "mpirun -np 2 ./a.out"?

Comment: Yes! I can run it and it gives me 2 identical statements since I have just 1 proc.

Comment: Do you know any other command instead of cc -O3 mpi_hello.c ? I think that the problem is just in the correct syntax which it has to be used for compilation!

Comment: Yes! It works but cc -O3 mpi_hello.c leaves the previous error message!

Comment: You cant compile OpenMPI with cc to my knowledge.  Thats what mpicc does.  BTW, if this answered your question please accept it=)

Comment: Okay wbt11a! Thank you for your answers. Do you mean that it is not necessary to compile with cc? just mpicc can do successfully the job?

Comment: Yes.  mpicc is the openmpi compiler.  You do not need to compile with cc - or you will get mpi.h not found error.  Also, make sure you run your mpicc compiled programs with mpirun.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure your include path is updated so the compiler can find mpi.h if it's not installed in a standard location.

Comment: I installed MPI in the same directory as the program. I think that there is a problem in the compilation command! Any help please? a

Comment: The local directory is not necessarily included in the include search path. Try #include "mpi.h" if the header file is in your local directory and check if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I doesn't work as well with#include "mpi.h". I succeeded to use mpicc but not cc -O3. Do you have any other suggestion please!? :/

Comment: Thank you Timo and wbt11a for your helps!!  :D